# Ошибка при настройке зависимостей с библиотеками android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

При настройке зависимости появилась ошибка:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':blocklylib-core:processDebugResources'.
>   Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.blockly.android'

Помогите исправить ошибку, не понимаю в чем дело

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mylti"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
debugCompile project(':blocklylib-core-debug')
releaseCompile project(':blocklylib-core-release')
}
```

Comment: Не надо скриншотов - надо скрипт сборки текстом.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавила текст сборки (вы это имели ввиду)?

Comment: Да, это) У вас (наверное и так понятно) два раза подключается либа с одни и тем же пакетом. Надо полагать что `debugCompile project(':blocklylib-core-debug')
releaseCompile project(':blocklylib-core-release')` не сработало. ПОпробуйте `build-clean` сделать. Если не поможет - давайте ссылку на либу (если она не ваша) либо что-то из самой либы, что отвечает за релизную/дебажную сборки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я делала по инструкции, это не мои библиотеки 
вот ссылка  https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/get-started/android 
Буду очень рада, если вы мне поможете разобраться, может я, что то не то делаю

Comment: Попробуйте так: `debugCompile project(path: ':blocklylib-core-debug', configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: ':blocklylib-core-release', configuration: "release")`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Нет, теперь ошибка другая 'Error:Configuration with name 'debug' not found.'

Comment: В этом случае единственно, что могу предложит - отказаться от одного из вариантов либы. Т.е. удалить либо дебаг, либо релиз зависимость.